# python, reg ex pattern into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with my regex pattern. What am I missing here?

```
pattern = r'^(?P<filename>Cycle Narrative(?P<nlookup>[A-Z0-9-]+).docx?$)' 
dfCycleNarratives = dftemp[dftemp.columns[0]].str.extract(pattern, expand=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

df temp looks like this:

```
                                           0
0    Cycle Narrative - Louis Stevens.docx
1  Cycle Narrative - Steve Stevens.docx
```

I am trying to get my `dfcyclenarratives` to look like:

```
  filename                nlookup
0      Cycle Narrative     Louis Stevens
1      Cycle Narrative     Steve Stevens
```

my `dfcyclenarratives` currently looks like:

```
  filename nlookup
0      NaN     NaN
1      NaN     NaN
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

What would it be like if the name came first in df temp, how could i get nlookup to still be the name?

```
                                           0
0    Louis Stevens - Cycle Narrative.docx
1  Steve Stevens- Cycle Narrative.docx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str.extractall`:

```
pattern = r'(?P<filename>.*)\s+-\s+(?P<nlookup>.*)\.docx'
dfCycleNarratives = dftemp[dftemp.columns[0]].str.extractall(pattern).reset_index(drop=True)
print(dfCycleNarratives)

# Output
          filename        nlookup
0  Cycle Narrative  Louis Stevens
1  Cycle Narrative  Steve Stevens
```

Comment: What you want is to extract only the "nlookup" part and keep "filename" as is?

Comment: ill clarify in the question.